# How can I deep link from a notification to a screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am trying to set up deep linking in my app. I have set up the app as well as the push notifications. However, I am unable to complete the final link from where the AppDelegate receives the user click on a notification to the screen that I want to deep link to. I basically want to call viewRouter.goToFred() from the AppDelegate. I have set up a git repo here (https://github.com/cameronhenige/SwiftUITestDeepLink) with an app that has everything set up except for this final piece. Could somebody help me figure this out? Here are the relevant pieces of code. Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List {

            ForEach(viewRouter.pets) { pet in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PetView(),
                    tag: pet,
                    selection: $viewRouter.selectedPet,
                    label: {
                        Text(pet.name)
                    }
                )
            }
                Button("Send Notification to Fred") {
                    viewRouter.sendNotification()
                }
                
                Button("Manually go to Fred") {
                    viewRouter.goToFred()
                }
            }
            

        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ContentView: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())

        }

}
    
}
```

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedPet: Pet? = nil
    @Published var pets: [Pet] = [Pet(name: "Louie"), Pet(name: "Fred"), Pet(name: "Stanley")]
    
    
    func goToFred() {
        self.selectedPet = pets[1]
    }
    
    func sendNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let categoryIdentifire = "Notification Type"
        
        content.title = "Go To Fred"
        content.body = "Click me to go to Fred."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.badge = 1
        content.categoryIdentifier = categoryIdentifire
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct PetView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        
        if let pet = viewRouter.selectedPet {
            Text(pet.name)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

struct PetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PetView()
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Pet: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id: String { name }

}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
    
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        return true
    }

}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
      withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("Notification created")

      // Change this to your preferred presentation option
      completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        print("user clicked on notification. Now take them to Fred.")
        //todo Somehow I want to call viewRouter.goToFred(), but I don't have access to that object in AppDelegate
        
      completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I try this approach and it works. Admittedly I dont know if this is the correct or suggested way.

The `appDelegate` has to get reference to the same `ViewRouter` instance that MainView is using, and where `ContentView` has to hook the `appDelegate` with the `ViewRouter` instance.

ContentView.swift:

```
@main
struct ContentView: App {
    
    let router = ViewRouter()
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
  
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(router)
                .onAppear(perform:setUpAppDelegate)
        }
    }
    
    func setUpAppDelegate(){
        appDelegate.router = router
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
weak var router: ViewRouter?
```

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
  let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    print("user clicked on notification. Now take them to Fred.")
    //todo Update the ViewRouter to
    router?.goToFred()
    
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am guessing this is probably the recommended way of doing this because it seems elegant. I wish Apple would provide more SwiftUI examples showing best practices for these types of things.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different pattern to accomplish something very similar, that doesn't require me to expose the environment object to the app delegate. In our case instead of a router, we have an app state container object, but ultimately it works in a very similar way.

I found that this was important to do because changing the values on appState requires that those changes happen from within the context of the `App`. If I updated the `path` property on `appState` from within the `AppDelegate` it resulted in a disconnect between the value on the instance of the injected `appState` object and the referenced `appState` object provided through the `.environmentObject` modifier. This caused views to receive the state changes down stream, but they could not send updates back upstream.

In `AppDelegate` add a published property

```swift
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

    @Published var userNotificationPath: String?

    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        userNotificationPath = userInfo["path"] as? String

        ...
    }
}
```

monitor the property from `App` for publications, and update the environment object `appState`.

```swift
struct MyApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    @StateObject var appState = AppStateContainer()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environmentObject(appState)
                .onReceive(appDelegate.$userNotificationPath) { path in
                  appState.path = path
                  appDelegate.userNotificationPath = nil
                }
        }
    }
}
```

monitor the `appState` value in any view needing to respond

```swift
struct SomeChildView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject private var appState: AppState
  
  var Body: some View {
    View()
      .onReceive(appState.$path) { path in
         ...handle business
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's well detailed in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions)

All you have to do is to call the method that you want to run when clicking on a notification in `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` in the AppDelegate

Comment: I got that part. However, if I put "@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter" in the AppDelegate, XCode throws an error "Unknown attribute 'EnvironmentObject'". So, the question is how do I call the method that I want to call if I cant instantiate it in the AppDelegate?